# LiveData List order/sort changed not triggering the observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a `LiveData<List<ReportRow>>` that gets updated when the user changes the date range or changes the sort order of the data that comes from a SQLite DB.

I have a observer to observe the data and update the UI with the changes. The observer triggers when the List has new or removed items, but if the amount of items is the same, just with a different sort order, the observer doesn't trigger.

How do I get the observer to trigger when the sort order changes?

Here is some of my code:
My Fragment Code:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getSalesReport()
        observeSalesReport()
    }

    private fun getReport() {
        viewModel.getSales(startDate, endDate, sortBy)
    }

    private fun observeSalesReport() {
       viewModel.salesByProduct.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
           (binding.products.adapter as SalesByProductAdapter).updateData(it)
    }
```

Adapter Code:

```
fun updateData(updatedSalesByProduct: List<SalesByProductViewData>) {
    salesByProduct = updatedSalesByProduct
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

This is my View Model code:

```
private val _salesByProduct: Flow<List<SalesByProductViewData>> = getSalesByProduct.salesByProduct.map { salesByProductList ->
    salesByProductList.map { it.toSaleByProductViewData() }
}

val salesByProduct: LiveData<List<SalesByProductViewData>> = _salesByProduct.asLiveData()

fun getSales(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, sortBy: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    getSalesByProduct.invoke(startDate, endDate, sortBy)
}
```

This is my SalesCacheImpl:

```
private val _salesByProduct: MutableStateFlow<List<SalesByProduct>> = MutableStateFlow(
    emptyList()
)

override val salesByProduct: Flow<List<SalesByProduct>> = _salesByProduct

override suspend fun invoke(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, sortBy: String) {
    _salesByProduct.value = dao.getSalesByProduct(startDate, endDate, sortBy).map {
        it.toSaleByProduct()
    }
}
```

Comment: you say you use a `LiveData` but I see a `Flow`. Did you post a wrong snippet?

Comment: @fshdn19 in the viewModel line 5 (val salesByProduct...) is LiveData

Comment: Can I see your code in `// Update UI`. I think the above code has no problems

Comment: @fshdn19 I updated my post's code to show the Update UI code and the adapter code

Comment: Do have remove your observer or remove observer by `lifecycleowner` in anywhere?

Comment: @fshdn19 nowhere at all, I just observe it and query for data as needed

Comment: Where did you call `observeSalesReport` ?

Comment: Can you show the code of your SalesByProduct class?

Comment: @fshdn19 I call it in the onViewCreated() function

Comment: @Tenfour04 the SalesByProduct is a data class with the properties; data class SalesByProduct(val id: Int, etc...)

Comment: Let me see your onViewCreated please

Comment: Your collector may be put on an unreachable code, so it didnt get the call

Comment: @fshdn19 I updated the fragment code snippet to show the onViewCreated function

Comment: Can you show us where you trigger the update when users enter new startDate, endDate or sortOrder? Is it getReport() and the values are global class variables?